# how to check if a certain key-value pair exists in array of hashes as json in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of hashes as `json`, so how to check my array of hashes contains a hash with a given key-value pair.

This is my `json`

```
[{"question"=>"0a2a3452", "answer"=>"bull"}, {"question"=>"58deacf9", "answer"=>"bullafolo"}, {"question"=>"32c53e5f", "answer"=>"curosit"}, {"question"=>"b5546bcf", "answer"=>""}, {"question"=>"0f0b314", "answer"=>""}]
```

I tried looping through the `json` array, but this is tedious, as I need to check that if that `json` has that hash with a given key-value pair

It's a questionnaire form, in which I have to perform an update on answers

```
 if !@client_find.nil?    
     @client_find.questionnaire
     params[:commit].each do |key, value|
       @json=[]
       @json = @client_find.questionnaire
      if !value.empty? && @json.include?(key)
        puts "blunderc "+ value.inspect
        @new_append = Hash.new
        @new_append[:question] = key
        @new_append[:answer]= value
        @json << @new_append
      end

       if !key.empty? && !value.empty?
         #logic
         @json.each  do |u|
           if (u.key? key)
             puts "bothu "+ u[key].inspect
             u[key] = value
           end
         end
       end
    end
```

Comment: You want to check if there's a key in ANY of the objects in the array or in ALL of tem?

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to check and when the condition is met or not met.

Comment: my key is unique, I just want to check if a particular key exists in my array of hashes or not

Comment: As @TamerShlash said please give some example of expected output.

Comment: _"if a particular key exists"_ – and what is that particular key?

Comment: i have updated the post u can check @Goku

Comment: @Stefan key is questionnaire id  "question"=>"0a2a3452"

Comment: @suman "question" is a key and "0a2a3452" is a value. What you have is a key-value pair.

Comment: yes key value pair, isnt that makes a json object(a key value pair) ?

Comment: @suman your question says _"how to check if a particular key exists"_ whereas you want to check whether your array contains a hash with a given key-value pair. That's a bit different, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefan  yes you are right, my bad I was confused, may be I wasn't very clear in expressing my doubt

Answer (score 6):

[Array#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) iterates through the array. In each iteration I check wether the current hash has the searched question key or not. If a hash is found [Array#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) returns true otherwise false.

```
array = [{"question"=>"0a2a3452", "answer"=>"bull"}, {"question"=>"58deacf9", "answer"=>"bullafolo"}, {"question"=>"32c53e5f", "answer"=>"curosit"}, {"question"=>"b5546bcf", "answer"=>""}, {"question"=>"0f0b314", "answer"=>""}]

search_for_key = '0a2a3452'

array.any?{|hash| hash['question'] == search_for_key}
```

Comment: I don't see it necessary to check for the existence of the key separately.

Comment: @TamerShlash: Yes, your right. A missing key results to nil, I forgot.

Comment: Thanks a lot guitarman, this worked,i upvoted your answer but i dont have much reputation it wont reflect

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you want to check the existence of a hash which has the key/value pair `"quesetion" => "some-value"`.

Here's how you can do it:

```
array.any? { |item| item['question'] == 'some-question-id' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering your are checking for a particular key exists or not

```
@json.any? {|obj| obj.key?(your_particular_key)
```

Comment: and how will it return true or false, as it has two condition, .any ? and .key?

Comment: As we are passing a block to to `any?`. it will be evaluated against every element in the array  @suman

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array using `Enumerable#select` to get only the hashes that contains the desired key.

```
filtered = my_hash.select { |item| item['desired_key'] }
```

That's possible because `nil` is falsey. If you input is a raw JSON you'll need to parse it to a Ruby hash using [`JSON#parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) or any other equivalent method.

`filtered` will give you all the hashes that contain the `desired_key`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ? 
Btw guitarman's answer is way better !

```
questions = [{"question"=>"0a2a3452", "answer"=>"bull"}, {"question"=>"58deacf9", "answer"=>"bullafolo"}, {"question"=>"32c53e5f", "answer"=>"curosit"}, {"question"=>"b5546bcf", "answer"=>""}, {"question"=>"0f0b314", "answer"=>""}]

result = questions.find { |question| question['question'] == "Bonour" }

if result.nil?
    puts "Not found"
else
    puts "#{result['question']} #{result['answer']}"
end
```

Comment: i dont want this result = questions.find { |question| question['question'] == "Bonour" }
i want to find that question id and replace it with new answer from params, basically a update action